# successfully compiled PHP, but exectue PHP with error: not found shared libraries libmcrypt.so.4

Tags: php, mcrypt

This is the full error:

```
salamander@Salamander-PC:/lib$ php -v
php: error while loading shared libraries: libmcrypt.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My compiling command:

```
  ./configure \
    --prefix=/usr/local/php7 \
    --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php7/etc \
    --with-libdir=lib64 \
    ......
```

I have installed libmcrypt and I found `whereis libmcrypt` showed `libmcrypt: /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.la /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.so`

the full shell [here](https://github.com/salamander-mh/SalamanderLnmpShell/blob/master/install.sh)
My OS is `ubuntu on windows`

Comment: Your lib dir is lib64 but your mcrypt is not in there. Try copying it in there. Also, **do not use mcrypt**.

Comment: use libsodium encryption of php 7.2. Its very simple and powerful encryption

Comment: mcrypt is depreciated try not to use it for latest versions of php > 7.0
Just if you're hell-bent on getting it installed you can find it here https://opensuse.pkgs.org/42.2/opensuse-update-oss/php7-mcrypt-7.0.7-14.3.1.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: I know mcrypt is depreciated. I didn't get errors after I installed php on CentOS. My current OS is `Linux Salamander-PC 4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
Ubuntu on windows

Comment: @apokryfos strange thing. After I copy `libmcrypt.so` to lib64 and renamed it to `libmcrypt.so.4`, I still got the error  
`salamander@Salamander-PC:/lib64$ ls
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  libmcrypt.so.4`

Comment: Using deprecated software is like using a leaky condom. You just don't do that.

Comment: @emix I got it. I will remove the mcrypt from my shell

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem with adding this line

`sudo apt-get install -y libmcrypt4`